# Working on a React App with 5000 eslint warnings. Any good approaches to fixing this?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app, eslint, prettier

I'm working on a codebase where create-react-app's default eslint warnings have been ignored for quite some time. Even after auto fix, the codebase is still left with ~4000 warnings.

**Why is this a problem?**

- The app works, but all the warnings make console warnings a pretty useless feature for my team since it's so hard to dig through all the warnings

**What am I looking for?**

- Something to mitigate the tediousness of brute-force fixing all the issues
- OR, I think the team can live with the warnings, but it would be great if there was a tool that surfaces the warnings and errors relevant only to any new modifications to the code. I know you can do something similar with prettier, husky, and pretty-quick where prettier is only run on staged files pre-commit. Is there something similar to this but with eslint?

**What am I NOT looking for?**

- I'm not looking to eject CRA or fork CRA. In my situation, it wouldn't be worth it to explore that route

Comment: Have you tried `eslint --fix`?

Comment: Check the automatic fixes [here](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/) (the ones with the wrench icon)

Comment: that's what i meant with "auto fix". Even after --fix, I still have a ton of errors